# Can't scale SVG in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an SVG in a React functional component:

```
import React from 'react';

function mySVG({ colour, width, height, scale }) {
    const scaleFactor = 'scale:(' + { scale } + ')';

    return (
        <svg width={width} height={height}>
            >
            <g transform={scaleFactor}>
               <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" 
                    fill={colour}
                    stroke={colour}
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                />
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
}

export default mySVG;
```

How come this is not scaling with according to the scale prop?

Comment: I think you have extra `>` in the code, also can you add  https://codesandbox.io/ example?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your syntax, it should be without `:` in `'scale(' + { scale } + ')';`

```
import React from 'react';

function mySVG({ colour, width, height, scale }) {
    const scaleFactor = 'scale(' + { scale } + ')';

    return (
        <svg width={width} height={height}>
            <g transform={scaleFactor}>
               <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" 
                    fill={colour}
                    stroke={colour}
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                />
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
}

export default mySVG;
```

I added codesandbox for it : https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-architecture-uw45f

Comment: Sorry changing the scale factor on the codesandbox - and when I use your code in my component that isn't working for me either?

Comment: Ok I took out the {} and it seems ok now - also your codesandbox works fine which is embarrassing but I swear there was some web glitch or something

Comment: Sometime it happens, its ok, glad to hear its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is named `mySVG` React Components must be uppercased, ie. `MySVG`.